# ReactJs: How to Reload/refresh/re-render component without using window.location.reload()

Tags: reactjs, reload

I want to **reload/refresh/re-render** my component but without using ‍‍‍`window.location.reload()`. Is there any possible way to do so. I have tried with **this.forceUpdate(**) and **this.setState({ state: this.state });** but these are not actually helping me in my case.

```
 testDoneHandler(e) {
    if( this.state && e.origin === document.location.origin ) {
      if( e.data === 'testingClosed' ) {
        this.setState({ state: this.state });
      
      }
    }
  }



 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('message', this.testingClosed.bind(this));
  }
```

Any suggestion/help would be helpful.Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want to refresh the component? Usually the main reason to re-render a component is because of prop/state change.

Comment: @LawynnJana so what do you suggest. can we just re-render this componen withour actually affecting the changes ?

Comment: https://reactgo.com/react-refresh-page/ according to this guide you could try `this.setState({});` to refresh a single component (I never tried)

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito i tried this but nothing actually worked for me.

Comment: @Tammy can you show more code such as what is in `render()` and how you initialize the `state`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
class t extends React.Component {
  state = {
    forceRerender: 0,
  };
  testDoneHandler(e) {
    if (this.state && e.origin === document.location.origin) {
      if (e.data === "testingClosed") {
        this.setState((value) => ({ forceRerender: value.forceRerender + 1 }));
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("message", this.testingClosed.bind(this));
  }

  console.log('forceUpdate', this.state.forceRerender);
}
```

Comment: Hi Taghi, thanks for your time. But this doesn't re-render. is anything i have missed ?

Comment: @Tammy Try adding a `log` like above to use that state and to see if the state is changing